# is type_alias unsupported in ndk toolchain?

Tags: android, eclipse, c++11, android-ndk

I'm porting a c++ project with bits of c++0x to android. Everything including c++0x features compiles and works fine, except stuff related to type_alias.

For example

```
for(const auto& p : paths) 
{
   ...
}
```

compiles, while

```
class dummy
{
    ...
    using t_pair = std::pair<std::string, int>;
}
```

doesn't, giving several errors

```
jni/dummy.h:31:8: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 't_pair'
jni/dummy.h:31:8: error: using-declaration for non-member at class scope
jni/dummy.h:31:15: error: expected ';' before '=' token
jni/dummy.h:31:15: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

If i place type_alias ouside class definition, it produces this

```
jni/dummy.h:39:7: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 't_pair'
jni/dummy.h:39:7: error: 't_pair' has not been declared
jni/dummy.h:39:14: error: expected ';' before '=' token
jni/dummy.h:39:14: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
```

I guess i have to mention that this compiles and works in vs13.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ...
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ...

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

I am using android-ndk-r9d with arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 toolchain (according to the eclipse console output). I have tried replacing -std=c++11 with -std=gnu++11 as well as gnustl_shared with stlport_shared, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Actually, this is not a big problem, and can be simply overwritten, but i wonder if it is a result of incomplete c++11 support, or maybe i am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use gcc 4.8. Add this to your Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue (and unfortunately raised some others, but that's outside the scope of the question).